# access Port Connectors (read/write fan rotation speed on Asus Winbond HW)

Tags: port, hardware, motherboard

I need to access Fan Speed.

Board is KGPE-D16 with Winbond W83667HGA.

I have got SMBIOS data about connectors and I need to read/write them

`[Port Connector Information] (Type 8)
08 09 17 00 01 FF 00 00 FF 46 52 4E 54 5F 46 41 .........FRNT_FA
4E 31 00 00                                     N1..

Type    0x08 (8)
Length  0x09 (9)
Handle  0x0017 (23)
Internal Reference Designator   String1 - "FRNT_FAN1"
Internal Connector Type 0xFF - Other 
External Reference Designator   NULL
External Connector Type 0x00 - None 
Port Type   0xFF - Other`

The problem is I never used to WDK and WMI things.
I am looking at Open-Hardware-Monitor and cannot understand how to insert in there.
I also have RWEverything but its command/adress system is hard to understand.
This problem is so simple - I just want read/write one number.

ADD1. Fan Speed is already controlled by BIOS. So I want to read it first.

ADD2. Doing in RWEverything should be easier. But I do not understand its CLI.

ADD3. In RWEverything there is command: `I{len} {port}`.
I did not get it work yet.

ADD4. The function that does IO looks like this

```
private byte ReadByte(byte bank, byte register) {
  Ring0.WriteIoPort(
     (ushort)(address + ADDRESS_REGISTER_OFFSET), BANK_SELECT_REGISTER);
  Ring0.WriteIoPort(
     (ushort)(address + DATA_REGISTER_OFFSET), bank);
  Ring0.WriteIoPort(
     (ushort)(address + ADDRESS_REGISTER_OFFSET), register);
  return Ring0.ReadIoPort(
    (ushort)(address + DATA_REGISTER_OFFSET));
} 

private void WriteByte(byte bank, byte register, byte value) {
  Ring0.WriteIoPort(
     (ushort)(address + ADDRESS_REGISTER_OFFSET), BANK_SELECT_REGISTER);
  Ring0.WriteIoPort(
     (ushort)(address + DATA_REGISTER_OFFSET), bank);
  Ring0.WriteIoPort(
     (ushort)(address + ADDRESS_REGISTER_OFFSET), register);
  Ring0.WriteIoPort(
     (ushort)(address + DATA_REGISTER_OFFSET), value); 
}
```

The function call that reads looks like this
`ReadByte(0, FAN_BIT_REG[i]);
ReadByte(FAN_TACHO_BANK[i], FAN_TACHO_REG[i]);`

Because this codes from OpenHardwareMonitor are stupidly retarded, I can not understand what the hell is 'address'.

Comment: You dont need WDK and stuff. Use WinRing0 or something. Some C# code adjusting my fanspeed on older motherboard https://github.com/leppie/TempServe/blob/master/TempServe/SuperIO.cs#L708

Comment: As I have found, I2C channels on my motherboard are closed, and this motherboard is really not a choice for any hardware enthusiast. It can be solved in hardware way: cut control wire from fan, or if that doesn't work (not for all PWM fans and Mobos), put it under approximately +1 volt above ground wire.

Comment: I doubt you need to use I2C for fan control. That chip normally is accessible via the ISA I/O port. The code from OHM is hardly stupid. Try understand it, and poke around with RWEverything. Reading the datasheet repeatedly and understanding it is very important. Depending on modes, settings can live in different registers. Do you have fan software provided from your MB manufacturer? Make snapshot before/after setting something and compare the banks.